# Integral defined by Bessel function

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

Let $J_0(x)=J(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{p=0} \frac{(-1)^p}{(p!)^2}(\frac{x^2}{4})^{2p} $ be the function Bessel of order 0. Take a cut-off function $k\in C^{\infty}_{0}(\Bbb{R})$ such that $k(x)=1$ on $]-1,1[$ and $k(x)=0$ if $|x|>=2$.

Define $I_n=\int^\infty_0 |J(nt)k(t)|^2 t^5 dt$.

My question is can we say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=0$.

Note: It is well known that $|J(x)|<=1$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$

Comment: Note that $k$ is zero if $x>2$ and that $J_0(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$. So you are integrating over a finite box and as $n$ gets larger you are compressing a function that becomes zero at infinity into this box.

Comment: Also note that the functional analysis tags explicitly states that it is for questions about function spaces, not about analytic properties of specific functions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, can I find an equivalent of $I_n\sim$